# Bottom Navigation Bar for All screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, bottom-navigation-bar

My aim is to achieve same bottom navigation bar in all screen for that I'm using below methods and package.

I am using below package

```
persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2: ^4.2.5
```

Issue is when I will redirect it from any screen using

`pushNewScreen(context, screen: screen, withNavBar: true);`

My app bar which is present in below screen is always showing in all screen. But I don't need AppBar in all screens expect below screen.

```
 List<Widget> pageList = [
    const HomePage(),
    const WearHouseScreen(),
    const OrderScreen(),
    const ProfileScreen(),
  ];
```

below is my main screen

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FancyDrawerWrapper(
      cornerRadius: 30.0,
      controller: fancyDrawerController!,
      backGroundImage: Assets.imagesDrawerBackground,
      drawerItems: DrawerScreen(fancyDrawerController: fancyDrawerController!),
      child: Obx(() {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: getUserType() != UserTypeEnum.Staff
              ? kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 0
                  ? getHomePageAppbar()
                  : kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 1
                      ? getWareHouseAppbar()
                      : kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 2
                          ? getOrderAppbar()
                          : getProfileAppbar()
              : kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 0
                  ? getOrderAppbar()
                  : kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 1
                      ? getWareHouseAppbar()
                      : kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value == 2
                          ? getMessageAppBar()
                          : getProfileAppbar(),
          body: PersistentTabView(
            context,
            controller: kmainController.tabController?.value,
            navBarHeight: 60,
            padding: const NavBarPadding.all(5),
            onItemSelected: (value) {
              kmainController.selectedBottomBarIndex.value = value;
            },
            screens: getUserType() == UserTypeEnum.Staff ? staffPageList : pageList,
            items: getUserType() == UserTypeEnum.Staff ? staffNavBar() : adminOwnerNavBar(),
            backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            hideNavigationBar: false,
            itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease),
            screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(animateTabTransition: true, curve: Curves.ease, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200)),
            navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (_) => ClassName(),
      ),
```

try this, it was working on my side,

pushNewScreen(
context,
screen:  yourClassName(),
withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
);

Comment: This does not work for as I need bottom navigation bar in all screens. And in my app there is approx 100 odd screens.